# Getting duplicate key when inserting after deleting row

Tags: sql, sql-insert, uniqueidentifier, delete-row

I’m doing:

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = '6B4AE2C6-7C26-4BB0-AEC2-9590A7A167F3' AND idFK='F3696D77-AC4A-4235-B6CB-C887D62FF860' AND data=3
```

(`Id` is a `PK uniqueidentifier` and `idFK` is a `FK uniquedientifier`, `not null` both. `Data` is `int` `not null`)

Then I do:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, idFK, data) 
VALUES ('6B4AE2C6-7C26-4BB0-AEC2-9590A7A167F3','F3696D77-AC4A-4235-B6CB-887D62FF860',6)
```

And here’s where I get the error:

Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.mytable' with unique index 'ixmytable'.

Here’s the select:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '6B4AE2C6-7C26-4BB0-AEC2-9590A7A167F3' AND idFK='F3696D77-AC4A-4235-B6CB-C887D62FF860' AND data=3
```

And what it shows:

```
------------------+ id +--                             ---+ idFK +------   -+ data 
6B4AE2C6-7C26-4BB0-AEC2-9590A7A167F3    F3696D77-AC4A-4235-B6CB-C887D62FF860    3
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: ` idFK='_F3` here is the space in value, so you select another row, not the "deleted" one, maybe it is problem?

Comment: thanks but I added the space accidentally when I was copiying the info here, no space in my script I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete a row from your table then for deletion only

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = '6B4AE2C6-7C26-4BB0-AEC2-9590A7A167F3'
```

is enough. But if you want to update particular value then you can try with

```
UPDATE mytable SET DATA = 6 WHERE id = '6B4AE2C6-7C26-4BB0-AEC2-9590A7A167F3'
```

Because `id` is an unique identifier, and it can be used to uniquely identify each row. And I think originally in your database the value of `idFK` column is having one space, so you are getting error.

```
//Third Query
idFK=' F3696D77-AC4A-4235-B6CB-C887D62FF860'
      ^
//But First and second query
idFK='F3696D77-AC4A-4235-B6CB-C887D62FF860'
```

Comment: copied and pasted your update: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.mytable' with unique index 'ixmytable'.

Comment: @user523129 Before inserting first you have to delete that particular row.

Comment: first query in my post

Comment: Yes, first query and I think there is a space in your database that's why you got the result in third query. Execute first query, and give one space before your idFK value. Or directly by putting ID try to delete the row.

Comment: thanks but I added the space accidentally when I was copiying the info here, no space in my script or database I'm afraid

Comment: Delete the row by simply giving query `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = '6B4AE2C6-7C26-4BB0-AEC2-9590A7A167F3'` let me know if your query executed successfully.

Comment: Now with second query `INSERT INTO mytable (id,idFK,data) 
VALUES ('6B4AE2C6-7C26-4BB0-AEC2-9590A7A167F3','F3696D77-AC4A-4235-B6CB-887D62FF860',6)` try to insert the values, let me know if this also works now

Comment: Executing the insert I get: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.mytable' with unique index 'ixmytable'

Comment: Hi there, currently I'm experiencing the same problem as you did half a year back. Did you manage to find a clean solution? 
(just asking here first to avoid creating a duplicate question)

Answer (score 0):

try to do this before insert :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
```

Comment: I get this error:
Table 'mytable' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.